# Proxmox -> photon -> docker -> plex gpu passthrough

Tags: linux, docker, proxmox, nvidia

I have recently setup a new proxmox server featuring a photon os VM for my docker images. It works great, i just have one issue... I cant seem to get my quadro P2000 passed to my plex for hardware transcoding.

I have found the GPU in proxmox and passed it to photon os, where i now also find it (the pci device that is). But when i look at passing through a gpu to a (plex) docker all i can find is passing the driver. Unfortunately there is no nvidia driver for photon os as far as i know. What should i do?

Comment: Use something other than Photon OS?

Comment: You are probably right. After another day of banging my head at a wall i am going to migrate everything to CentOS. Thank god for docker